# Improving Tesseract Accuracy

Tags: python, tesseract

I am running OCR on these type of Images
[image]

The Problem is whenever there is a digit it is getting confused between 8 and 2 , 5 and 6 and even sometimes misses one digit .
e.g. in claim number output was "0320 0051 0.200801 000012 >" when run (psm 11).

Is there any way i can improve accuracy over these images.

Comment: I guess you need better quality images - can you capture the images in a lossless format like PNG? Or use lower JPEG compression?

Comment: Which tesseract version you use? Which model?

Comment: i am using the latest version "tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha".

Comment: @barny yeah i will give that a try